# Determining who modified a certain line of code (a.k.a. "blame feature")

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

We have a very complex project where severals file might be modified by many (let say 50) different users. Occasionally, in order to understand and make changes to a code block, you need to contact the person who wrote that line/code block/method. So what you do is you go through all changesets until you find the one you were looking for.

Is there a built-in feature to find the author of a line/code block/method in Visual Studio Team Explorer 2012 directly?

If not, is there a third-party tool that has this feature?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate has this feature called code lens. It also requires TFS 2013. It will show all recent checkins and work items etc. Hopefully they will make it available to other editions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, I have found a solution I was looking for. There is a feature called Annotate:

[image: Menu]

And here is the result:

[image: History]

Comment: Also known as the blame feature. Make sure you compare to previous before you kill the offender, this feature can make mistakes and that's something you can't undo.

Comment: Blame feature, hahaha, gotta love it.